# Efficient aggregation over time index in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, python-datetime

I have data in weekly format that I want to aggregate to the monthly level in an efficient way. What I currently doing is reindexing the DataFrame from weeks to days and then taking the mean over days within each month. This approach is slow, especially as I am dealing with large data. I am looking for a more efficient way.

**Simplified example**

The weekly data:

```
dates = ['2018-8-20','2018-8-27','2018-9-10']
values = [1,2,3]

df = pd.Series(values, index=pd.to_datetime(dates))
df.index.name = 'week'
df.name = 'val'
```

Turned into daily (note that I am forward filling the nulls):

```
date_list = [df.index.min() + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (df.index.max()-df.index.min()).days+1)]
dfDaily = df.reindex(date_list)
dfDaily=  dfDaily.fillna(method='ffill')

dfDaily = pd.DataFrame(dfDaily)
dfDaily['month'] = dfDaily.index.month
dfDaily['year'] = dfDaily.index.year
```

which gives:

```
            val  month  year
week                        
2018-08-20  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-21  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-22  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-23  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-24  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-25  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-26  1.0      8  2018
2018-08-27  2.0      8  2018
2018-08-28  2.0      8  2018
2018-08-29  2.0      8  2018
2018-08-30  2.0      8  2018
2018-08-31  2.0      8  2018
2018-09-01  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-02  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-03  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-04  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-05  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-06  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-07  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-08  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-09  2.0      9  2018
2018-09-10  3.0      9  2018
```

Aggregation to the monthly level:

```
dfMonthly = dfDaily.groupby(['year', 'month']).val.mean().reset_index()
```

resulting in the desired DataFrame:;

```
   year  month       val
0  2018      8  1.416667
1  2018      9  2.100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your solution, but not sure if big improvement of performance:

```
date_list = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='d')
s = df.reindex(date_list, method='ffill')

dfDaily = s.groupby([s.index.year.rename('year'),
                     s.index.month.rename('month')]).mean().reset_index()
print (dfDaily)
   year  month       val
0  2018      8  1.416667
1  2018      9  2.100000
```

Comment: Yes it's about 3 times as fast